# python nltk.sent_tokenize error ascii codec can't decode

Tags: python, nltk

I could successfully read text into a variable but while trying to tokenize the texts im getting this strange error :

```
sentences=nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I do know the cause of error is some special string/char which the tokenizer isnt able to read/decode but then how to bypass this?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell, NLTK3's pos_tag function doesn't work.

The NLTK2 function works fine, however.

> pip uninstall nltk
>
> pip install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nltk/nltk-2.0.4.tar.gz

On the other hand, the tagger is pretty bad (apparently 'conservatory' is a verb). I wish SpaCy worked on Windows.