# How do I fix this UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python

The stemmer as well as lemmatizer seem to produce this error for certain sentences passed to my textfile. What do they mean and how do I solve them?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "preproc.py", line 89, in <module>
        apos=stem_data(nostop)
      File "preproc.py", line 51, in stem_data
        r=stemmer.stem(n)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 632, in stem
        stem = self.stem_word(word.lower(), 0, len(word) - 1)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 590, in stem_word
        word = self._step1ab(word)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 275, in _step1ab
        if word.endswith("sses"):
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What are the sentences that are generating the errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python nltk.sent\_tokenize error ascii codec can't decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212912/python-nltk-sent-tokenize-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some kind of non-ascii character, so it's an encoding issue.. It would help to know which sentences are producing this error

Comment: This one: An artist’s impression of the galaxies found in the Zone of Avoidance behind the Milky Way is shown in this undated illustration, provided by the International Centre for Radio Astronomy Research on Feb 24. An Australian telescope used to broadcast live vision of man’s first steps on the moon in 1969 has found hundreds of new galaxies hiding behind the Milky Way using an innovative receiver that measures radio waves

Comment: Change your encoding to utf-8. Should fix the issue.

Comment: But then I get this again: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I did this:  r=wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(n.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: The problem is this character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Comment: Essentially the apostrophe in artist's is the problem. Try using utf-16 or utf-32

Comment: Oh and read this fantastic article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html